# how to get http response status + returned data in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use Http in angular2/ionic2.

My service code is

```
    getImageQuestionsFromServer(id:string){
    let questions = this._http.get(`http://abcd.com/cbsapp/package_content/${id}/image_questions.json`).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    return questions;
  }
```

My component code is

```
this._userDataService.getImageQuestionsFromServer(this.passedPackage.id)
            .subscribe(
            (data) => console.log(data.status),
            (err) => console.log(err)
            )
```

I dont know how to check the Http status codes inside my component. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service method:

```
getImageQuestionsFromServer(id:string){
  return this._http.get(`http://abcd.com/cbsapp/package_content/${id}/image_questions.json`);
}
```

Component method:

```
this._userDataService.getImageQuestionsFromServer(this.passedPackage.id)
            .subscribe(
            (response) => {
              let status = response.status
              let data = response.json();
            },
            (err) => console.log(err)
            );
```